How can I Filter Drive API list results by a domain with write permission
I am trying to get a list of files from the drive API with a service account, that allow a specific domain to edit them. I have it working for specific emails without issue, but I also need to be able to list them based on domains with write permission.
My query works as I expect when filtering by a specific email:
const query = `'some-id' in parents and 'abc@example.com' in writers`
const response = await DRIVE_API.files.list({
  q: query,
  fields: "files(id, name, mimeType, description)",
});
console.log("response.data:", response.data)

When I change the query to: const query = "'some-id' in parents and 'example.com' in writers and... The file list is empty.
I have verified that it should work by checking the permissions. Permissions on multiple files look like this:
permissions: [
    {
      id: '1234...',
      displayName: 'test',
      type: 'user',
      kind: 'drive#permission',
      emailAddress: 'test@example.com',
      role: 'writer'
    },
    {
      id: '1234...',
      displayName: 'some name...',
      type: 'domain',
      kind: 'drive#permission',
      role: 'writer',
      domain: 'example.com'
    },
    ...


You can search using the query:
visibility = 'domainCanFind' OR visibility = 'domainWithLink'
And filter the domain you want in the permissions.
